# How to complete remove filestream and all attached files

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have tried the FILESTREAM feature for MSSQL (2008R2 Data Center) on a local database, to experiment. The real database is running on a server. I have setup the whole FILESTREAM, using this query:

```
/* CREATE FILESTREAM AND FILESTREAM TABLE */
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE SenONew
ADD FILEGROUP [FileStream]
CONTAINS FILESTREAM
GO
ALTER DATABASE SenONew
ADD FILE
(
NAME = 'fsSenONew',
FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SenONew.ndf'
)
TO FILEGROUP [FileStream]
GO

USE [SenONew]
GO
CREATE TABLE Filestore(
    FileID int PRIMARY KEY,
    RowID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    FileDescr nvarchar(max),
    FileIndex varbinary(max) FILESTREAM NULL)
GO
```

And I was experimenting with adding a few files then deleting them.

Now since this was only meant to be an experiment, I also want to get rid of it. I'm using my local server for the development of the database that will be used on the real server, thus I'm creating BackUp's on my local server then Restore this on the real server, so it gets updated (software is in development, so the database structure changes much as well as the data and I need to do a full restore to the real server, where the software is being tested on).

After hours of searching, I couldn't find anything on my problem.

I understand that I need to:

1. Remove the database table storing the FILESTREAM information
2. I need to remove the FILE of the FILESTREAM
3. Remove the filegroup

So I'm using this query to get rid of everything I set up in the first place:

```
/* DROP FILESTREAM TABLE AND FILEGROUP */
USE SenONew
DROP TABLE Filestore
GO

ALTER DATABASE SenONew
REMOVE FILE fsSenONew

ALTER DATABASE SenONew
REMOVE FILEGROUP [FileStream]
GO
```

So I do everything as I should and it completes without error as well. So when I enter my filegroups, files and my file location, I see they are all completely removed:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But when I do a BACKUP of my local database (which include the deleted FILESTREAM, file path and filegroup) and try to restore the server with it, I get errors.

SQL to create a BACKUP:

```
/* CREATE BACKUP OF DATABASE WITHIN CURRECT CONNECTION */
DECLARE @FileName2 nvarchar(250)
SELECT @FileName2 = (SELECT 'C:\SenO BackUp\' + convert(nvarchar(200),GetDate(),112) + ' SenONew.BAK')
BACKUP DATABASE SenONew TO DISK=@FileName2
GO
```

[image]

Then do the Restore on the server:

```
/* CREATE RESTORE OF DATABASE WITHIN REAL SERVER CONNECTION */
use master
alter database SenONew set offline with rollback immediate;

DECLARE @FileName2 nvarchar(250)
SELECT @FileName2 = (SELECT '' + convert(nvarchar(200),GetDate(),112) + ' SenONew.BAK')
RESTORE DATABASE SenONew
FROM DISK = @FileName2

alter database SenONew set online with rollback immediate;
```

I get the following error:

[image]

*(Msg 5121, Level 16, State 2, Line 7 
The path specified by "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SenONew.ndf" is not in a valid directory.

Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 7 File 'fsSenONew' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SenONew.ndf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. )*

I deleted the .ndf FILESTREAM location, why is it a specified path? Also, why is fsSenONew trying to restore? I can't get my head around it. Are there paths internally that I need to delete?

Comment: Might I suggest that Backup and Restore isn't the best way of developing a database? It might work okay for now but as soon as the database is *used* in production, it'll no longer be a viable approach (unless wiping production data is okay). Under that assumption, why not develop the alternative approach that you'll need later now?

Comment: Backup and Restore seems to work perfect for the time being. As I mentioned earlier, the database structure changes a lot due to it's development phase. At the very end of the project, the finished database structure will be filled with the real current company data. Only after that will the new software be used in production, and any changes will only be made on the real server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check:

```
SELECT * FROM SenONew.sys.data_spaces WHERE name = 'FileStream'
```

it should return 0 rows.

There is a procedure to remove FILESTREAM features from a SQL Server 2008 database :

```
ALTER TABLE Filestore DROP column FileIndex
GO
ALTER TABLE Filestore SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO
ALTER Database SenONew REMOVE FILE fsSenONew
GO
ALTER Database SenONew REMOVE FILEGROUP [FileStream]
GO
```

as described in [this article](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10406/completely-removing-filestream-features-from-a-sql-server-2008-database.aspx). But the steps you did should do the same thing.

Your problem is certainly strange, but I suggest that you try using following

```
USE SenONew
EXEC Sp_help 
EXEC Sp_helpfile 
EXEC Sp_helpfilegroup
```

You may find something suspicious there like another table using that FILEGROUP.

I have done exactly the steps you describe and cannot reproduce your problem. Check how your Restore database screen looks like.

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is really weird. I tried to do the restore once again and it suddently worked, mine as well as your queries. The day I posted this, I have restarted all SQL services, checked and unchecked the FILESTREAM option, which then gave me a configuration error I have been trying to resolve for a pretty long time - computer reboot had fixed that problem - but even then I couldn't do the restore. Today, for some reason, I can.

I appreciate your reproduction, and therefore accepted it, and indeed, this is strange.

Comment: Yes, it was also my impression that it is not a standard and easily reproducible situation. Glad that you have worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

1.Remove the FILESTREAM attribute from columns and tables. You'll need to move data to a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD FileData varbinary(max) NULL;
GO
update MyTable
set FileData = FileStreamData
GO  
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
DROP column FileStreamData
GO
ALTER TABLE MyTable SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO
EXEC sp_RENAME 'MyTable.FileData', 'FileStreamData', 'COLUMN'
GO
```

2.Remove files from the FILESTREAM and drop the FILE and FILESTEAM.

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY Simple 
GO

EXEC SP_FILESTREAM_FORCE_GARBAGE_COLLECTION 

ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] REMOVE FILE [MyFile]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] REMOVE FILEGROUP [MyFileGroup]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
```

Comment: Why do you alter the database and set the recovery to simple and then full again?

Answer (score 0):

This is my script that worked for me. It was a command missing, to empty the file:

```
ALTER TABLE FilesTable DROP column FileContent
GO
ALTER TABLE FilesTable SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO


USE mydbname
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'filestreamfile', EMPTYFILE)
GO


EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection @dbname = N'mydbname'

ALTER Database mydbname REMOVE FILE filestreamfile
GO
ALTER Database mydbname REMOVE FILEGROUP FILESTREAMGROUP
GO


IF COL_LENGTH('FilesTable','FileContent') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE FilesTable ADD FileContent [varbinary](max)   NULL
END
GO
```