# SQL Server : deleting FIELSTREAM files and num_unprocessed_items

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

I'm trying to delete the actual binaries from the file system while using SQL Server `FILESTREAM`.

When doing so (and after removing all records that refers the `BINARIES` table) and running `EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection` the  `num_unprocessed_items` is increasing and the actual binary still exists in the FS.

For the sake of this post `BINARIES` is the table holding the blobs.

I'm calling

```
DELETE FROM BINARIES
```

and then I'm twice calling

```
EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection
```

What can be the reason and if possible, I'll be glad to get a step by step explanation (I'm not a DBA).

Thanks,
R.

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802310/how-to-complete-remove-filestream-and-all-attached-files

Comment: if you read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492195(v=sql.110).aspx "Items may be unprocessed for various reasons, including the following: Files that need to be pinned down because Log backup or CheckPoint has not been taken." Have you done an initial backup of this database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified my comment is correct. You have to perform a backup on your database before you can successfully garbage collect on it. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492195(v=sql.110).aspx

"Items may be unprocessed for various reasons, including the following: Files that need to be pinned down because Log backup or CheckPoint has not been taken."